# Can I select only one subelement if there are repetitive names?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm parsing a XML provided by a webservice and I'm trying to get somo information: It's a report from a electric smartmeter. The next is a part of the XML:

```xml
<Report IdRpt="S04" IdPet="0" Version="3.1">
  <Cnc Id="CUR9737960375">
    <Cnt Id="LGZ0019800498">
       <S04 Fhi="20190401000000000W" Fhf="20190501000000000S" Ctr="1" Pt="0" Mx="157 W" Fx="20190430200000000S">
          <Value AIi="2632 Wh" AEi="0 Wh" R1i="0 varh" R2i="0 varh" R3i="7094 varh" R4i="884 varh"/>
          <Value AIa="20461 Wh" AEa="0 Wh" R1a="0 varh" R2a="0 varh" R3a="147960 varh" R4a="8044 varh"/>
       </S04>
       <S04 Fhi="20190401000000000W" Fhf="20190501000000000S" Ctr="1" Pt="1" Mx="157 W" Fx="20190430200000000S">
          <Value AIi="2632 Wh" AEi="0 Wh" R1i="0 varh" R2i="0 varh" R3i="2650 varh" R4i="885 varh"/>
          <Value AIa="15218 Wh" AEa="0 Wh" R1a="0 varh" R2a="0 varh" R3a="59520 varh" R4a="6145 varh"/>
       </S04>
...
```

I want to get each Value parameter depend of Pt S04 parameter. I'm able to get each Value parameter and each Pt separates, but I need each Value for Pt=0, Pt=1...

I've tried the next, but I had to much measures and didnt match with the reality. Thats beacause, the loop access for each Value part and not for the proper value

```py
...
S02_list = ['AIi','AEi','R1i','R2i','R3i', 'R4i']

for medida in S02_list:
    for parse in tree.iter('S04'):
    Pt = parse.get('Pt')
    for intento in tree.iter('Value'):
        z = str(intento.get(medida))
        if z != 'None':
            print ('El valor de '+medida+' para Pt= '+Pt+' es: '+z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate on `parse` object in `for intento in tree.iter('Value'):` instead of on `tree`, so that will change to `for intento in parse.iter('Value'):`, then your code will change to

```
S02_list = ['AIi','AEi','R1i','R2i','R3i', 'R4i']

for medida in S02_list:
    for parse in root.iter('S04'):
        Pt = parse.get('Pt')
        #Iterate on parse
        for intento in parse.iter('Value'):
            z = str(intento.get(medida))
            if z != 'None':
                print('El valor de ' + medida + ' para Pt= ' + Pt + ' es: ' + z)
```

The output will look like

```
El valor de AIi para Pt= 0 es: 2632 Wh
El valor de AIi para Pt= 1 es: 2632 Wh
El valor de AEi para Pt= 0 es: 0 Wh
El valor de AEi para Pt= 1 es: 0 Wh
El valor de R1i para Pt= 0 es: 0 varh
El valor de R1i para Pt= 1 es: 0 varh
El valor de R2i para Pt= 0 es: 0 varh
El valor de R2i para Pt= 1 es: 0 varh
El valor de R3i para Pt= 0 es: 7094 varh
El valor de R3i para Pt= 1 es: 2650 varh
El valor de R4i para Pt= 0 es: 884 varh
El valor de R4i para Pt= 1 es: 885 varh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your most inner for loop is looping over all the Value elements in the tree, not just the children of the S04 that you are currently looping through. Try this instead:

```
for intento in parse.iter('Value'):
```

If print order isn't critical, you could also change the order of your loops to scan the tree only once:

```
for parse in tree.iter('S04'):
    Pt = parse.get('Pt')
    for intento in parse.iter('Value'):
        for medida in S02_list:
            z = str(intento.get(medida))
            if z != 'None':
                    print ('El valor de '+medida+' para Pt= '+Pt+' es: '+z)
```